# Boundary of event for point process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

In probability theory (notably convergence of stochastic processes), the concept of an event with probability zero boundary appears in several places. I want to make sure I am understanding this concept correctly.

For the notion of "boundary" of an event to make sense, it suffices to have a topology of open sets in addition to the sigma-algebra of measurable sets. Normally, we are working with the Borel sigma-algebra with some natural sense of open set which can normally be understood as generated by a known metric.

Let $X_t$ be a Poisson point process with intensity $\lambda$. I consider the probability space consisting of all realizations of this point process on $[0,\infty)$. Each realization is just a countable collection of points indexed by the times they occur at. I use the standard notion of metric and topology induced on this space by the Skorokhod metric & topology on the space of count paths. This is all standard theory as can be seen from Billingsley *Convergence of Probability Measures*. Of course point processes are also developed differently, as random measures, see, e.g. a standard graduate text such as Achim Klenke *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course*.

Quickly, the metric and topology induced on the space of all point process realizations applies less "weight" to arrivals that occur later in time, and considers two realizations to be close when their arrivals on some large finite time interval are close. If we have realization $\omega$, then perturbing some faraway arrival from time $t$ to time $t\pm\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon>0$ creates a new realization of the process that is in some small "open ball" around $\omega$.

Consider event
$$E=\{\text{at least $n$ points in the interval $[0,5]$}\}.$$
This event $E$ is all countable subsets of $[0,\infty)$ where the interval $[0,5]$ has at least $n$ points.
I want to make sure I understand what $\partial E$ is:
$$\partial E=\{\text{exactly $n-1$ points in the interval $[0,5)$ and exactly one point precisely at 5}\}.$$

This is clearly a probability zero event since it specifies a point at a specific location:
$$\mathbb P(E)=\frac{e^{-5\lambda}(5\lambda)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\cdot \mathbb P(\text{exactly one point precisely at 5})=0.$$

I think of this  in terms of the Skorokhod topology on the space of count paths. My thinking is that if $\omega\in\partial E$, then there should be an arbitrarily small slight perturbation of the points that "pushes it" out of $E$ and of course an arbitrarily small slight perturbation that pushes it into $E$. This seems to me to require an arrival to occur exactly on the edge of the time index interval and exactly $n-1$ in the interior, $[0,5)$; I don't include the possibility of an arrival exactly at time $0$ since perturbations can only keep that arrival into the time index interval $[0,5]$.

Another example:
Consider the Bernoulli process with only $k$ trials and some $n\leq k$. This naturally comes with the discrete topology. So the event $E=\{\text{at least $n$ successes}\}$ has empty boundary.

Now the Bernoulli process with infinitely many trials is a bit trickier, but I am thinking of a metric on this space like $d(\omega,\phi)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{2^j}|\omega_j-\phi_j|$ so that later trials contribute less. Consider the event $E=\{\text{infinitely many $1$'s}\}$. It seems like the boundary of this event is the entirety of $\Omega$ since every sequence has an arbitrarily small perturbation (in the sense of the stated metric) that makes it have infinitely-many ones and an arbitrarily small perturbation that makes it have finitely-many ones. I like to think of this $E$ as being the same as the set of rational numbers in $[0,1]$ with binary decimal expansions (essentially, neglecting some issues for a measure zero set, e.g. numbers with multiple decimal expansions), and this metric is essentially like standard Euclidean distance, so it makes sense that the boundary is the entire interval $[0,1]$. Of course we can change the topology to get different answers for the boundary here, e.g. neglect all trials after some finite index.

Please correct any of my thinking here!

Comment: The fact that your example $\partial E$ has probability zero follows directly from the definition of [Poisson point process on the real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_point_process_on_the_real_line). What is there that one could not understand correctly ? If you want to build your own intuition of this that's fine.

Comment: The reason for calling $\partial E$ a boundary of $E$ could simply be this: If you consider the number of points in question as the dimension of some $\mathbb R^n$ then $E$ corresponds obviously the full hypercube $[0,5]^n$. In contrast, $\partial E$ corresponds to one face  of $[0,5]^n$ and has dimension $n-1$.

Comment: @KurtG. The hypercube view is helpful though it's not perfectly clear to me how the topologies and measures transfer over. I imagine it is sufficiently similar to like a summation of scaled Lebesgue measures or similar so that measure zero is at least preserved. The "at least $n$ arrivals" event would then be all hypercubes dimension $n$ and larger, which makes determining the boundary geometrically like this a bit more unclear to me. The boundary still only is the edge of the $n$ dim cube. But you are not saying there are any mistakes in my post?

Comment: You may want to give some background about this boundary nomenclature. I have heard it for the first time. Are we sure it has anything to do with topology ? Boundary can mean many other things. See for example Martin boundary in potential theory.

Comment: @KurtG. Ok, I'll try to provide a reference in the post. Quickly, Billingsley Convergence of Probability Measures is where I am really coming from, the Skorohod topology on cadlag sample paths is relevant.